# How to pass values to the react app while loading the URL.?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

Suppose I have a React js project running on 3000 port, I can pass some values using query string e.g.

```
http://localhost:3000/?P1=XXXXXXXXX&P2=YYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

and can read them as P1 and P2 in componentDidMount() block.

Is there any another method to pass values while loading the URL as I want to pass large amount of parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most commonly a react application fetches initial data from an api that has to be provided by the backend and in most cases that is recommended. But you can also let the server embed initial data into the html, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = {foo: 'bar'};
</script>
```